# Nothing happens at a part of my script where there should be calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started programming with python 3.5 and in this first program that I am making nothing happens at this part of the program:

```
 def gender():
        var2 = input ("What is your gender? ")
    v1 = int (var4)
    v2 = int (var5)

    guyheight = v1+v2+13
    girlhiehgt = v1+v2-13

    v4 = guyheight/2
    v5 = guyheight/2

    if var2 == 'boy' or var2 == 'Boy' or var2 == 'guy' or var2 == 'Guy' or var2 == 'male' or var2 == 'Male' or var2 == 'man' or var2 == 'Man':
        print ("Your estimated full-fledged height is, {}.".format(v4))
    elif var2 == 'girl' or var2 == 'Girl' or var2 == 'female' or var2 == 'Female' or var2 == 'woman' or var2 == 'Woman':
       print ("Your estimated full-fledged height is, {}.".format(v5))
    else:
        print ("Sorry, your gender is invalid. Please re-enter the answer.")
        gender()
```

Comment: You need a [mcve]. What does "nothing happens" mean?

Comment: what do you mean nothing happens? No print at all?

Comment: `v5 = guyheight/2` -> `v5 = girlheight/2`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, but this shouldn't lead to "nothing happening"

Comment: @jphollowed. Agreed, which is why I did not make it into an answer. Unless we know what `var2,4,5` are and where they come from, OP will probably get closed down pretty soon.

Comment: OP, once this program has been fixed, may I strongly suggest checking out [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? Beginners often end up coding in a not very readable style, and it's best to get pointers on how to avoid that early on. :)

Answer (score -1):

This answer is based on my guess that `gender()` is this entire function and you want it to repeat at the end if a valid answer is not given. Try the formatting below.

```
def gender():
    # There's obviously some code up here that eventually gives us var1 - var5
    # I'll assume var2 is an input from the user

    var2 = input("Enter your gender")

    v1 = int(var4)
    v2 = int(var5)

    guy_height = v1 + v2 + 13
    girl_height = v1 + v2 - 13

    v4 = guy_height / 2
    v5 = guy_height / 2

    if var2.lower() in ('boy', 'guy', 'male'):
        print ("Your estimated full-fledged height is, {}.".format(v4))

    elif var2.lower() in ('girl', 'female', 'woman'):
        print ("Your estimated full-fledged height is, {}.".format(v5))

    else:
        print ("Sorry, your gender is invalid. Please re-enter the answer.")
        gender()

gender()
```

Comment: Don't use recursion if you need a loop.

Comment: @Eric - I agree, though if it were just the `if - elif - else` statements I don't see the problem.

Comment: I updated the question to include the def gender() part of the script. Thanks

Comment: Show us your entire code formatted correctly and we might be able to help.